# Preview form in a template based on a dropdown options in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am working on an application that will preview HTML emails.

On the initial creation page, I want the user to be able to preview the email before submitting it.

Here is what I have so far

views.py

```
def mail_create(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)          
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MailForm(request.POST)         
        if form.is_valid():
          if '_preview' in request.POST:
              post = form.save(commit=False)
              context_dict = {}
              subject_line =  form.cleaned_data['subject_line']
              headline = form.cleaned_data['headline']
              mail_body = form.cleaned_data['mail_body']
              image = form.cleaned_data['image']
              context_dict = {} 
              context_dict['mail'] = mail
              context_dict['subject_line'] = subject_line
              context_dict['headline'] = headline
              context_dict['mail_body'] = mail_body
              context_dict['image'] = image 
              t = form.cleaned_data['template']
              preview = t.render(Context(context_dict))
              return HttpResponse(preview)
          elif '_save' in request.POST:
              form.save(commit=True)
              return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posta.mail'))
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = MailForm()       
    return render_to_response('mail_create.html', {'form' : form}, context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from posta.models import Mail, mail_template, Image
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=140, help_text="Please enter a name for your email.")
    subject_line = forms.CharField(max_length=140, help_text="Please enter the subject line for your email.")
    target = forms.CharField(max_length=140, help_text="Who is this email going to?")
    date_scheduled = forms.DateField(help_text="When do you need this email sent?",
                                     widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'datepicker'}))    
    template = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=mail_template.objects.all(), help_text="Select a Template")
    headline = forms.CharField(max_length=140, help_text="Please enter a headline for your email.")
    mail_body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    image = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Image.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Mail
        fields = ('name','subject_line','target','date_scheduled','template', 'headline', 'image', 'mail_body')
```

When I click the preview button, I get this error 
Exception Value:

```
'mail_template' object has no attribute 'render'
```

Should I be using render to response? With the template being the data from the form template selection?

EDIT: Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Mail(models.Model):
    DRAFT = 0
    READY = 1
    SENT = 2
    STATUS_CHOICES= ((DRAFT, 'Draft'),(READY, 'Ready'), (SENT, 'Sent'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140, unique=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_scheduled = models.DateField()
    target = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    template = models.ForeignKey('mail_template')
    subject_line = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    mail_body = models.TextField()
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=DRAFT)
    image = models.ForeignKey('Image')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery/')

class mail_template(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    template_body = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Example mail_template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>{{mail.subject_line}}</title>
</head>

<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#FAFAFA; width:100%; ">
    <center>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="backgroundTable" style="margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#FAFAFA; height:100%; width:100%; ">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse; ">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateContainer" style="border:0; background-color:#FDFDFD; ">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse; ">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateHeader" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; border-bottom:5px solid #505050; ">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" class="headerContent" style="border-collapse:collapse; color:#202020; font-family:Arial; font-size:34px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding:10px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; ">
                                            <div class="mktEditable" id="column_text1">
                                                <img title="{{mail.subject_line}}" src="{{ mail.image}}" alt="{{mail.subject_line}}" height="120" width="600">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse; ">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateBody">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top" class="bodyContent" style="border-collapse:collapse; background-color:#FDFDFD; ">
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse; ">
                                                        <div mc:edit="std_content00" style="color:#505050; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; line-height:125%; text-align:justify; ">
                                                            {{ mail.body }}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
    </center>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The line `t = form.cleaned_data['template']` makes no sense. The value will be a `mail_template` Django model object, but it needs to be a `Template` object in order to be rendered. What's it supposed to do?

Comment: @MikeDeSimone I have a dropdown on the MailForm that will select the Template that needs to be rendered. I was trying to reference the selection made in the dropdown to render the form in.  Do I need to reference the template like 'mail.template.template_body' ? I've added my template model to the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that explains things. The problem is that you're not creating an actual `Template` object at any point. Changing two lines will fix it:

```
def mail_create(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)          
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MailForm(request.POST)         
        if form.is_valid():
          if '_preview' in request.POST:
              post = form.save(commit=False)
              # ...
              t = form.cleaned_data['template']
              tmpl = Template(t.template_body)             # <--
              preview = tmpl.render(Context(context_dict)) # <--
              return HttpResponse(preview)
```

Make sure you have `from django.template import Template` up top.

BTW, `mail_template.name` should really be a  `CharField`.

Comment: Just test this out. The preview button works now but doesn't populate any of the form data. I'm thinking its a similar error as that I'm not acutally creating a 'Image' object or creating the mail_body object?

Comment: Hard to say since you don't really say what's in your template. You might note that the context you pass to `tmpl.render` doesn't have `form` in it.

Comment: I owe you a beer or something :) . I've added an example of the mail_template to the original question. Doesn't form.cleaned_data grab the data needed to populate the template? Or is that data lost at the rendering point?

Comment: I'll take a "this answer worked" and an upvote in lieu of a beer. The template can *only* work with what it is passed in its context; it has no access to things outside that context. A `RequestContext` only seems to have access to other things because of the "context processors" (in settings.py) which can alter the context; they don't get to do this to plain old `Context` contexts. So `form.cleaned_data` may be filled, but if it's not passed into the template's context (like you did in the line `render_to_response('mail_create.html', {'form' : form}, context)`), the template can't use it.